# How to rotate a model on a plane?

Tags: rotation, three.js

I am using a plane geometry to represent a terrain model with different "y" values(altitude). Also using the raycaster function I am able to move the model on the plane.

1. I need a way to rotate the model a be parallel with the current face its on without changing its path orientation.
2. Is there a way to define rotation by a face of a geometry?

Comment: You can get the normal of the face you are interested in and then do a `Object3D.rotateOnAxis (axis, angle)` (from http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D)

Comment: And what would be the axis and what the angle?

Comment: `axis` would be the normal of the face around which you want to do a rotation. `angle` is by how much you want to rotate.

Comment: i want to rotate as much as needed to be parallel to the face that's moving. This is the question.

Answer (score 0):

theCorrect me if I'm wrong here, it sounds like you want to have both local (on the face) and global (in the direction of your "path orientation") rotations integrated here. This is, in general, one of those tricky and somewhat context-specific problems that will require you to mix two different sources of rotation. In a typical Euler-style rotation, it sounds like you want to rotate around Y according to the path (I'm assuming the path is in top-down 2D here -- it's these assumptions tat make the problem impossible to definitively answer!), while rotating around X and Z according to the normal of the surface. Try taking assembling a THREE.Euler that way -- does it get you in the neighborhood?

Comment: I am studying the Euler angles but i don't see why the rotation is not working..In my previous research i found how  to rotate the model.I rotated in Z first which is the orientation rotation and an the X and Y afterwards. The thing is that in big angles or after some rotations the models was changing orientation. Thats why i am looking other methods