# Rotate a moving model to be parallel on a plane geometry

Tags: rotation, three.js

I am trying to rotate a model on a plane geometry that represents a hill. I use the following code. My problem is that though the model see to have the correct rotation when start animating and is parallel to the face it is moving when getting near and overcoming the point(0,0,0) it is rotating weirdly. Maybe the problem that I have set the up of the model to be the vector(0,0,1) (you can copy paste to an editor and view the example on your browser):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>three.js webgl - trackball controls</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
                <style>
                    body {
                        color: #000;
                        font-family:Monospace;
                        font-size:13px;
                        text-align:center;
                        font-weight: bold;

                        background-color: #fff;
                        margin: 0px;
                        overflow: hidden;
                    }

                    #info {
                        color:#000;
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0px; width: 100%;
                        padding: 5px;

                    }

                    a {
                        color: red;
                    }
                </style>
        </head>

            <body>
                <div id="container"></div>
                <div id="info">
                    <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - trackball controls example</br>
                    MOVE mouse &amp; press LEFT/A: rotate, MIDDLE/S: zoom, RIGHT/D: pan
                </div>

                <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

                <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

                <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
                <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

                <script>

                    if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

                    var container, stats;

                    var camera, controls, scene, renderer,mesh,animation,morph;

                    var cross;

                    init();
                    animate();

                    function init() {

                        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                        camera.position.z = 500;

                        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

                        controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
                        controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
                        controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

                        controls.noZoom = false;
                        controls.noPan = false;

                        controls.staticMoving = true;
                        controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

                        controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];

                        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

                        // world

                        scene = new THREE.Scene();
                        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100,100,2,2);
                        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff0000,side:THREE.DoubleSide,
                                        polygonOffset: true,
                                        polygonOffsetFactor: 1, // positive value pushes polygon further away
                                        polygonOffsetUnits: 1});
                        var vertices = geometry.attributes.position.array;  
                        vertices[ 14 ] =10;
                        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
                        scene.add(mesh);
                        // wireframe
                        var helper1 = new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh, 0x000000 ); // or THREE.WireframeHelper
                        helper1.material.linewidth = 2;
                        scene.add( helper1 );

                        // lights

                        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                        light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        scene.add( light );

                        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
                        light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
                        scene.add( light );

                        light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
                        scene.add( light );


                        // renderer

                        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                        renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
                        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                        container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
                        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                        container.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
                        stats = new Stats();
                        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                        stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
                        container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
                        container.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
                        //

                        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
                        //

                        render();

                        }

                        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                            color: 0x0000ff
                        });
                        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                        geometry.vertices.push(
                            new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -20 ),
                            new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 20 )
                        );

                        var helper = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
                        scene.add( helper );

                        //////////

                        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
                        loader.load( "http://threejs.org/examples/models/animated/horse.js", function( geometry ) {

                            morph = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x606060, morphTargets: true } ) );
                            morph.scale.set( 0.02, 0.02, 0.02 );
                            //morph.rotation.set(Math.PI/2,Math.PI/2+Math.PI/4,0);//rotate to look at the direction moving.
                            morph.position.set(-50,-50,0);
                            scene.add( morph );

                            animation = new THREE.MorphAnimation( morph );
                            animation.play();

                        } );

                    /////////
                    //raycaster function 
                    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

                    function onMouseMove( event ) {

                        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
                        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

                        raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

                        // See if the ray from the camera into the world hits one of our meshes
                        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh );

                        // Toggle rotation bool for meshes that we clicked
                        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {



                            helper.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
                            helper.lookAt( intersects[ 0 ].face.normal );

                            document.body.style.cursor = "crosshair";
                            helper.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );
                            render();
                        }
                        else{document.body.style.cursor = "auto";}

                    }

                    function onWindowResize() {

                        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                        controls.handleResize();

                        render();

                    }

                    function animate() {

                        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                        render();
                        controls.update();
                    }
                    var prevTime = Date.now();
                    function render() {



                        if ( animation ) {

                            var time = Date.now();

                            animation.update( time - prevTime );

                            prevTime = time;

                        }
                        if(morph){
                        if(morph.position.x>50){morph.position.x=-50;morph.position.y = -50;}
                        morph.position.x+=0.3;
                        morph.position.y+=0.3;
                        var help = helper.clone();
                        help.position.set(morph.position.x,morph.position.y,-10);


                        var ray= new THREE.Raycaster();
                        ray.set(help.position,new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1).normalize());
                        var intersect = ray.intersectObject( mesh );

                        // Toggle rotation bool for meshes that we clicked
                        if ( intersect.length > 0 ) {
                            morph.up.set(0,0,1);
                            morph.position.copy( intersect[ 0 ].point );
                            morph.lookAt( intersect[ 0 ].face.normal );
                        }
                        }
                        renderer.render( scene, camera );
                        stats.update();
                    }




                </script>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Any ideas to keep the models rotation parallel to the face it is on?

Similar question with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626899/how-to-rotate-a-model-on-a-plane) that has no answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate a model on a plane?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626899/how-to-rotate-a-model-on-a-plane)

Comment: This is the same question i say it at the last line of the question.But this is with more details and also i added to this one my code and made it more spesific :) any thoughts to solve?

Comment: I added these logging lines to see what's going on and the face where the raycast hit changes when the rotation starts to change which makes a lot of sense of course. You could inspect more what face it hits near the center etc.

`console.log(intersect[ 0 ].face, intersect[0].point, intersect[ 0 ].face.normal);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have take the code above and after playing with it for a while was able to get the effect you were going for but maybe not the way that answers your question... here is what i have found anyway...  and another note i think i was working with the code that was first posted.. 
so it's been a long time scene i have dealt with 3d code (2001-2002 time frame) so my knowledge may be both rusty and out of date with newer trends. plus i am new to this frame work.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>three.js webgl - trackball controls</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
            <style>
                body {
                    color: #000;
                    font-family:Monospace;
                    font-size:13px;
                    text-align:center;
                    font-weight: bold;

                    background-color: #fff;
                    margin: 0px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }

                #info {
                    color:#000;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0px; width: 100%;
                    padding: 5px;

                }

                a {
                    color: red;
                }
            </style>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container"></div>
            <div id="info">
                <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - trackball controls example</br>
                MOVE mouse &amp; press LEFT/A: rotate, MIDDLE/S: zoom, RIGHT/D: pan
            </div>

            <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

            <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

            <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
            <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

            <script>

                if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

                var container, stats;

                var camera, controls, scene, renderer,mesh,animation,morph;

                var cross;

                init();
                animate();

                function init() {

                    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                    camera.position.z = 500;

                    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

                    controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
                    controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
                    controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

                    controls.noZoom = false;
                    controls.noPan = false;

                    controls.staticMoving = true;
                    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

                    controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];

                    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

                    // world

                    scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100,100,2,2);
                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff0000,side:THREE.DoubleSide,
                                    polygonOffset: true,
                                    polygonOffsetFactor: 1, // positive value pushes polygon further away
                                    polygonOffsetUnits: 1});
                    var vertices = geometry.attributes.position.array;  
                    vertices[ 14 ] =10;

                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
                    scene.add(mesh);
                    // wireframe
                    var helper1 = new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh, 0x000000 ); // or THREE.WireframeHelper
                    helper1.material.linewidth = 2;
                    scene.add( helper1 );

                    // lights

                    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                    light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                    scene.add( light );

                    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
                    light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
                    scene.add( light );

                    light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
                    scene.add( light );


                    // renderer

                    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
                    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
                    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                    container.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
                    stats = new Stats();
                    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
                    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
                    container.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
                    //

                    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
                    //

                    render();

                    }

                    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                        color: 0x0000ff
                    });
                    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                    geometry.vertices.push(
                        new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -20 ),
                        new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 20 )
                    );

                    var helper = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
                    scene.add( helper );

                    //////////

                    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
                    loader.load( "http://threejs.org/examples/models/animated/horse.js", function( geometry ) {

                        morph = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x606060, morphTargets: true } ) );
                        morph.scale.set( 0.02, 0.02, 0.02 );
                        //morph.rotation.set(Math.PI/2,Math.PI/2+Math.PI/4,0);//rotate to look at the direction moving.
                        morph.position.set(-50,-50,0);
                        scene.add( morph );

                        animation = new THREE.MorphAnimation( morph );
                        animation.play();

                    } );

                /////////
                //raycaster function 
                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

                function onMouseMove( event ) {

                    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
                    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

                    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

                    // See if the ray from the camera into the world hits one of our meshes
                    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh );

                    // Toggle rotation bool for meshes that we clicked
                    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {



                        helper.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
                        helper.lookAt( intersects[ 0 ].face.normal );

                        document.body.style.cursor = "crosshair";
                        helper.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );
                        render();
                    }
                    else{document.body.style.cursor = "auto";}

                }

                function onWindowResize() {

                    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                    controls.handleResize();

                    render();

                }

                function animate() {

                    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                    render();
                    controls.update();
                }
                var prevTime = Date.now();
                function render() {
var DelX,DelY,DelZ,LastZ;
DelX=0.3;DelY=0.3;

                    if ( animation ) {

                        var time = Date.now();

                        animation.update( time - prevTime );

                        prevTime = time;

                    }
                    if(morph){
LastZ=morph.position.z;
                    if(morph.position.x>50){morph.position.x=-50;morph.position.y = -50.1;}
                    morph.position.x+=DelX;
                    morph.position.y+=DelY;
                    var help = helper.clone();
                    help.position.set(morph.position.x,morph.position.y,-10);


                    var ray= new THREE.Raycaster();
                    ray.set(help.position,new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1).normalize());
                    var intersect = ray.intersectObject( mesh );

                    // Toggle rotation bool for meshes that we clicked
                    if ( intersect.length > 0 ) {
                        morph.up.set(0,0,1);
                        morph.position.copy( intersect[ 0 ].point );
DelZ=morph.position.z-LastZ;
var PointToLookat = new THREE.Vector3(morph.position.x+DelX,morph.position.y+DelY,morph.position.z+DelZ);
morph.lookAt( PointToLookat );
                        // old morph.lookAt( intersect[ 0 ].face.normal );
                    }
                    }
                    renderer.render( scene, camera );
                    stats.update();
                }




            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

so basically your LookAt is "pointing" the horse at some point in 3d space at first i assumed it was a vector direction and maybe that what you were assuming too, i at least was wrong, so you have to put your point "in front" of the current position of the object. i added some delta vars and kept track of the lastZ position value (as i write this i realized i could have used a vector for that) so i found the "next spot" the object will be at and used that as the PointToLookat.

Comment: and how can someone use a vector for that? can you edit your answer or reply somehow? Great work btw! :)